# Adding a 'post to everyone' option in Drupal Commons

Tags: 7

At present, Drupal Commons posts must be added to one or many groups or to trusted contacts. I would like to add a "public" post that everyone can see in their feed. This is simply a meta group that all members belong to given that my community is a smaller, private intranet.

So, I would like the post to have 3 options. 1) Post to a group(s), 2) post to trusted contacts, 3) post to the community.

Has anyone implemented this ?

Comment: So to clarify, you want the post to be assigned to this meta group on "Post to Community" or do you want it to appear in all groups?

Comment: Hi webkenney, I want the post to be seen by all users in their feed, preferably not once they have opened a specific group. These messages would not be group topic related.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have enough information to help. Just because something is listed as a Group Post (i.e. something that can be posted into a group) doesn't mean it needs to be. In other words, by nature of not selecting any groups you are effectively leaving the piece of content out of the group context.

Then, I might consider simply modifying the view which powers the user feed (this is a view that ships with Commons) and including non-group posts with a specific flag/tag. So to recap:

- Create a tag (using taxonomy) or a flag (using [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)) that effectively denotes a piece of content being non-group specific. e.g. public
- Instruct your users by way of a bit of help text on the node type that they should use that tag and not post into a group.
- Modify the view powering a user's feed (I think this is called Activity Stream IIRC) to include your newly tagged or flagged content.
- Fancy bonus: Use a bit of JavaScript to disable the group field if either of the above flag/tag conditions are true. (Pseudo-Code: `if node has tag public then disable list box`)

That should get you there. Hope this helps.

Comment: That sounds like a good method, I'll give it a try now. Thank you very much!